# Как сортировать элементы списка по нескольким атрибутам последовательно?

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, сортировка, анализ-данных

Есть список, который нужно отсортировать. Сперва по `new_name`, потом по `nf`, потом по `no`. Основная сложность, это колонка `no` и `nf`. Не могу привести их к типу `int`, поэтому приходится использовать *натуральную сортировку*.

Как соединить оба запроса в один?

P.S. `new_name, nf, no` сгенерированы из поля `name`.

```
def natural_sort_key(s, _re=re.compile(r'(\d+)')):
    return [int(t) if i & 1 else t.lower() for i, t in enumerate(_re.split(s.no))]

sorted_1 = sorted(data, key=operator.attrgetter('new_name','nf'))
sorted_2 = sorted(data, key=natural_sort_key)



name:'ТП 2-1/400-Ф1-1-ЖБ'
new_name:'ТП 2-1/400-Ф1'
nf:'Ф1'
no:'1'

name:'ТП 2-1/400-Ф2-2-ЖБ'
new_name:'ТП 2-1/400-Ф2'
nf:'Ф1'
no:'2'

name:'ТП 2-1/400-Ф2-2/1-ЖБ'
new_name:'ТП 2-1/400-Ф2'
nf:'Ф2'
no:'2/1'

name:'ТП 2-1/400-Ф10-1/1-ЖБ'
new_name:'ТП 2-1/400-Ф10'
nf:'Ф10'
no:'1/1'
```

На выходе должен получиться такой порядок:

```
ТП 2-1/400-Ф1-1-ЖБ
ТП 2-1/400-Ф2-1-ЖБ
ТП 2-1/400-Ф2-2/1-ЖБ
ТП 2-1/400-Ф10-1/1-ЖБ
```

Пробую вот так:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([t.__dict__ for t in data])
        
import natsort as ns

df['nf'] = pd.Categorical(df['nf'], ordered=True, categories= ns.natsorted(df['nf'].unique()))
df['no'] = pd.Categorical(df['no'], ordered=True, categories= ns.natsorted(df['no'].unique()))
       
df.sort_values(['new_name', 'nf','no'], ascending=[True, True,True])
```

Видно, что сортировка по `nf` работает, а вот `no` вообще неправильно отсортировало:

```
                name      nf  no       new_name
0     ТП 2-1/400-Ф1-1-ЖБ  Ф1   1  ТП 2-1/400-Ф1
1    ТП 2-1/400-Ф1-10-ЖБ  Ф1  10  ТП 2-1/400-Ф1
2    ТП 2-1/400-Ф1-11-ЖБ  Ф1  11  ТП 2-1/400-Ф1
3    ТП 2-1/400-Ф1-12-ЖБ  Ф1  12  ТП 2-1/400-Ф1
4    ТП 2-1/400-Ф1-13-ЖБ  Ф1  13  ТП 2-1/400-Ф1
..                   ...  ..  ..            ...
810  ТП 8-1/160-Ф1-75-ЖБ  Ф1  75  ТП 8-1/160-Ф1
811  ТП 8-1/160-Ф1-76-ЖБ  Ф1  76  ТП 8-1/160-Ф1
812  ТП 8-1/160-Ф1-77-ЖБ  Ф1  77  ТП 8-1/160-Ф1
813   ТП 8-1/160-Ф1-8-ЖБ  Ф1   8  ТП 8-1/160-Ф1
814   ТП 8-1/160-Ф1-9-ЖБ  Ф1   9  ТП 8-1/160-Ф1

[815 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def get_num(col):
    return col.str.extract(r"(?P<x>\d+)")["x"].astype("int16")

res = (df
       .assign(nf1=get_num(df["nf"]), no1=get_num(df["no"]))
       .sort_values(["new_name", "nf1", "no1"])
       .drop(columns=["nf1", "no1"]))
```

результат:

```
In [80]: res
Out[80]:
                  name  nf  no       new_name
0   ТП 2-1/400-Ф1-1-ЖБ  Ф1   1  ТП 2-1/400-Ф1
1  ТП 2-1/400-Ф1-10-ЖБ  Ф1  10  ТП 2-1/400-Ф1
2  ТП 2-1/400-Ф1-11-ЖБ  Ф1  11  ТП 2-1/400-Ф1
3  ТП 2-1/400-Ф1-12-ЖБ  Ф1  12  ТП 2-1/400-Ф1
4  ТП 2-1/400-Ф1-13-ЖБ  Ф1  13  ТП 2-1/400-Ф1
8   ТП 8-1/160-Ф1-8-ЖБ  Ф1   8  ТП 8-1/160-Ф1
9   ТП 8-1/160-Ф1-9-ЖБ  Ф1   9  ТП 8-1/160-Ф1
5  ТП 8-1/160-Ф1-75-ЖБ  Ф1  75  ТП 8-1/160-Ф1
6  ТП 8-1/160-Ф1-76-ЖБ  Ф1  76  ТП 8-1/160-Ф1
7  ТП 8-1/160-Ф1-77-ЖБ  Ф1  77  ТП 8-1/160-Ф1
```